# Fetch All SubAccount Usage Resource of Twilio Main Account

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am new in PHP and twillio. I am trying to fetch all type usage information of my sub accounts. Basically I want store this information in my google sheet and need this value
[image]

I am able to fetch all my sub accounts SID like below

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid  = "my main account sid";
$token = "my token";

$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$accounts = $twilio->api->v2010->accounts
                               ->read([], 20);

$items = array();
foreach ($accounts as $record) {
    $items[] = $record->sid;
   
}
 print_r($items);
?>
```

This is fine. I can loop my all sub account inside forearch for get usage. For Fetch usage I am following [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record?code-sample=code-one-month-date-range-inbound-calls-only&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x)

and code is like below

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid  = "my main account";
$token = "my token";

$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$records = $client->usage->records->read(
    array(
        "category" => "sms-outbound",
        "startDate" => "2021-02-01",
        "endDate" => "2021-02-28"
    )
);

// Loop over the list of records and echo a property for each one
foreach ($records as $record) {
    echo $record->price;
}
?>
```

Currently I am getting cost of my main account.

I am not getting idea How I can get cost of MY sub account with different type usage which I have mentioned in above image. I am not getting idea that I am following correct API guideline for achieve my goal or not. Let me know if someone here can guide me for same or can give me example.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that you are making the API request on behalf of your main account, so you get the data from that account. To [make a request on behalf of a subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts?code-sample=code-make-a-call-from-a-subaccount&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x), you should add the subaccount SID to the API client, like this:

```php
$sid = "main account sid";
$subaccountSid = "subaccount sid";
$token = "main account token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token, $subaccountSid);
```

Then, when you make requests using this `$client` they will be made against the subaccount.

Comment: Thanks! It have helped me lot!